# How to use maven3 SCM:update-subprojects?

Tags: maven, maven-3, maven-scm, maven-scm-plugin

This may be a dumb question,and I cannot really find anything on the web or in apache's maven3 SCM documentation.

I'm aggregating a jar from several modules. The aggregator is a peer/sibling of the other modules. At this point, making the aggregator and modules in a hierarchical structure is not possible.

The question is how do structure the pom to update modules using SCM:update-subprojects ?  I'm really looking for a simple example..

Comment: Are those modules related to each other? If yes you should make a single repository out of it and a multi module build from it...

Comment: The modules are interdependent and have different life cycles. The scm is git, and it doesn't do modules very cleanly. I would much prefer clearcase.  Eventually this source tree needs to be reconfigured, but that's a year away

Comment: If those modules are interdependent than I don't understand the question..so each project can simply being updated via `git pull`? Furthermore you should setup a CI solution like Jenkins to build things and use multi branch pipelines to build feature branches etc.

Comment: @khmarbaise Yes I fully agree with you!! An automated pipeline is in the near future, but not right now. Its not my code base, and as a result it hard to change the structure, but I'm working on it. I would like to move to clear case, but that's not a viable solution today. I'm working on a hierarchical solution to build the main library if I can figure out how to launch scm before module dependency checking fails the build.  This is not helping me figure out update-subprojects which is my easiest solution.

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by `...before module dependency checking fails the build..`..The only way to work with separate projects which have interdependencies is to have a repository manager and each build should `mvn clean deploy` into the repository..from there any other can consume the dependency?...

Comment: You're on the other issue. :).  I get an error: [ERROR] [ERROR] Some problems were encountered while processing the POMs: <path to pom>. I'm assume scm  needs to be in a earlier phase. Reactor is looking to the pom before the checkout occurs.

Comment: I would suggest to update the modules from outside via usual git commands instead of trying to go via Maven. I really don't see any advantage to go via. But you can try to do via `mvn -N org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-scm-plugin:1.11.2:update-subprojects` ?

Comment: Thanks.. Its almost better/easier to just write a git shell script at this point..